# How many pixels of an image can iphone display horizontally without scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone

OK, so I've been reading iphone 4's screen resolution is "640x960".

So I created a web page with an image sized 600x300 inside.

Now, when I access the web page, it just shows around half of the image and I have to scroll to the right to see it all. During my search I read that iphone 4's pixels count 2 for 1 CSS pixel blah blah.

Can someone clarify this for me? So iphone 4 cannot display an image sized less than 640 pixels wide "normally" ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 'correct' resolution is 320x480. The Retina display doubles the resolution, but adds the notion of 'points', so developers don't have to make two versions of same application.
[Here](http://globalmoxie.com/blog/designing-for-iphone4-retina-display.shtml) you can read more about it.